# Get location in background AND when app is terminated

Tags: ios, iphone, location

Is there a way to get

1.
Location notification when the app is in the background

2.
Location notification After the app is terminated

3.
When terminated - get the location notification for movement of less than 500 meters

ALL IN SAME APP?

(i've seen articles that says you should use

```
[myLocationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
```

INSTEAD of -

```
[myLocationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

can i use both?)

thanks

Comment: I'm going to assume that you cannot gather location information when the app has been terminated, as that ends all processes related to the app. You can however, do it in the background. In fact, there's a specific flag in your info.plist you need to enable before you can do it.

Comment: you actually CAN gather information after the app been terminated (feature from iOS 7.1) - according to some articles i'm currently trying to implement this feature.